# Очистить счетчик id mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Подскажите как в mysql очистить счетчик Auto Increment?
Тестировал свой скрипт, хочу обнулить счетчики id у записей

Comment: ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 [Более детальная инфа здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`truncate table tablename` помимо очищения данных ещё и сбрасывает auto increment.

Или

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

id - это не счетчик, и к счетчикам ни малейшего отношения не имеет.

Обнулять его никогда не нужно.

Если вдруг засвербило "обнулить", это значит, что автоинкрементное поле в таблице не нужно, и его следует просто удалить.

Просто для красоты обнулять тоже нет смысла. Таблица в БД - это не новенькая кофтачка с розочками, чтобы на нее любоваться. Тем более что через два дня эксплуатации от красивости все равно не останется ни следа.