# По настоящему удалить строки из таблицы базы данных

Tags: mysql, sql

Первый раз пишу сюда, не судите строго и да, да, глубоко извиняюсь за скрины.
Кратко: создал базу данных, в таблицу добавил данные (строки, которые нумеруются по первому столбцу). Нужно было очистить таблицу, Сделал это через DELETE. Добавляю новый элемент, нумерация осталась со старых элементов. Т.е. элемент в таблице один, а в столбце, где его нумерация, цифра 3 (это первый скрин). А теперь внимание, элемент у меня один, с номером 3. Я вывожу через команду SELECT строку под номером 1 и под номером 2 (столбец называется firm_num), и SQL выводит строки которых даже нет в моей таблице!!! (скрины 2 и 3). Защиту от новичков выключал, не помогает. Все команды видны внизу каждого скрина, проследить мои действия может каждый.
[image: Вот пример, все команды видны снизу, нумерация осталась, объектов нет(но сейчас докажу обратное)]
[image: Вот пример, когда я ищу первую строчку]
[image: Вот пример, когда я ищу вторую строчку]

Comment: я ничего не понял

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Очистить счетчик id mysql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499039/%d0%9e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba-id-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

`id` - это уникальный номер записи. Этот номер берет из счетчика (auto increment). При удалении записи он остается прежним. Это сделано специально? чтобы как пример избежать проблем с релацией между таблицами по ключу. При необходимости можно его изменить.

Запрос в селекте `SELECT firm_num=1 ...` - не приведет ничему полезному. Для фильтрации используется оператор `WHERE`. `SELECT ... FROM` - вместо троеточие говорим, что хотим получить.